# How to find relocation table info for ppc

Tags: elf, powerpc, dwarf

I found https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/ELF/ppc64/PPC-elf64abi.html#RELOC-TYPE but that seems like it is from 2004 based on the copyright. Is there anything newer or is this still accurate information? I'm not sure if this is something that is keep backwards compatible.

Comment: Are you looking for 32-bit, 64-bit ABIv1 or 64-bit ABIv2 (LE)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm looking specifically for ppc64le, so I would assume 64-bit ABIv2. I didn't think there would be a difference for BE vs LE

Comment: You need ABIv2 for LE. _technically_ you can do BE with ABIv2, and I think some small distros do, but by and large BE is still on ABIv1. I'll post a link in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've found the ABIv1 spec. It's still used today for lots of 64-bit Big Endian work. You'd not expect it to change too quickly, being an ABI.

For 64-bit Little Endian, you want the ABIv2 specification. It's available from the OpenPower foundation at https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=64-bit-elf-v2-abi-specification-power-architecture